# express-openid-connect error crashes server

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the express-openid-connect library. I noticed that when there is a problem with the server I want to connect to, it results in an error that crashes my app.

It is mentioned that errors raised by express-openid-connect are handled by the default Express error handler. See: https://github.com/auth0/express-openid-connect#getting-started

As far as I can tell I did implement an error handler, but it never seems to reach that. I created a simplified sample that causes an error (on purpose). My question is, what do I need to do prevent Node from crashing but catches the error and send a response.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { auth } = require('express-openid-connect');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8081

app.use(
    auth({
        baseURL: 'http://some.domain',
        secret: '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        clientID: 'clientid',
        issuerBaseURL: 'http://some.domain'
    })
);


app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    // I expect this to run but it never does.
    console.log('ERROR', err);
    res.end('Something went wrong')
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

You can trigger the scenario by starting the server and go to http://localhost:8081/login

Comment: If you for debugging, `process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) { console.log(err) })`, does it log anything helpful?

Comment: Not really. It shows the error that was already printed. The question is how can I make sure that NodeJS doesn't crash and unfortunately catching the error this way does not prevent that. Catching uncaught exceptions is of course wise to do anyway.

Comment: What is the actual error? I'm just curious if it's an error that will crash the app regardless, not necessarily something that happens in a route handler.

Comment: The error is about not being able to reach the oidc server. This can happen from time to time. I would like to inform my visitors that they cannot login temporarily. But I can't because the system crashes. I think it is reasonable to at least be able to respond. My example above simulates that error.

Comment: Did you ever solve it @WalterBrand ?

Comment: thanks for asking. I prayed the oidc server would never go down. And it never did. Running the example again with the newer packages from express and express-openid-connect now seem to work properly. It now sends a 'something went wrong' when the error occurs.